# Including extra files in a Python package's unittest test suite

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, testing

I'm working on a small Python package, and I'm writing unit tests for it. I have my package structure laid out in fairly typical Python fashion:

```
mypackage/
    mymodule.py
    test/
        test_mymodule.py
```

This particular module is designed to read the contents of a file, do a thing with said contents, and then return a value. In order to test this, I want to include some input files in my test suite.

I suppose I could organize them like this:

```
mypackage/
    mymodule.py
    test/
        test_mymodule.py
        test_input01.txt
        test_input02.txt
```

And then locate the files to read using the `__file__` global variable.

My question is: is this a reasonably Pythonic way of organizing things? I'm concerned that guessing paths in this manner won't be reliable in any environment (e.g., if the package is installed via pip or etc.).

Specifically, I'm looking for either 1) some official documentation that supports this (or some other) approach, or 2) a well-regarded existing project that uses this (or some other) approach.

Comment: It's pretty much ok to use `__file__` for locating the current directory path and a place where the test data lives. As an example, see [pep8](https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8) github project, particularly pay attention to how tests are organized in `testsuite` package - `*.py` files there with names like `E10.py`, `E11.py` are used as target files in tests. Hope that helps.

Comment: You are very right - they do indeed use this exact technique. If it's good enough for the Python style guide, it's good enough for me. :) Add that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much ok to use `__file__` for locating the current directory path and a place where the test data lives.

As an example, see [pep8](https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8) github project, particularly pay attention to how tests are organized in `testsuite` package - `*.py` files there with names like `E10.py`, `E11.py` are used as target files in tests.

Also, [pylint](https://github.com/geordanr/pylint) uses similar approach (based on `__file__`), but the test data is organized in [subpackages](https://github.com/geordanr/pylint/tree/master/test).

Also, see:

- [How to make python unit tests always find test data files when run from different working directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361503/how-to-make-python-unit-tests-always-find-test-data-files-when-run-from-differen)
- [How can I store testing data for python nosetests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724072/how-can-i-store-testing-data-for-python-nosetests)

Hope that helps.

Comment: In particular, one can see them using `__file__` to locate the test directory here: https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/blob/master/testsuite/support.py, and then using that constant to load test input files here: https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/blob/master/testsuite/test_api.py. It seems like this is a reliable way to implement this. :)